# What's the preferred way to get reference to actor by name that's input parameter?

Tags: akka

Provided I'm getting the name of an actor as an input parameter, say from a call to  `http://example/restservices/{actorname}`.

What would be the preferred way to get a reference to an actor:

```
Akka.system.actorOf(Props[MyActor], name = actorname) ! SOMETHING("some1")
```

or

```
Akka.system.actorSelection("/user/"+actorname) ! SOMETHING("some1")
```

?

Comment: It depends on whether the actor exists in the system or not.

Comment: This is pretty similar to an answer I recently gave: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27254663/akka-actor-selection-without-race-condition/27256148#27256148

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you need to use depends on whether you have an existing Actor which can handle your message or not. Using `actorOf` in your case i risky because you provide a name for an actor and by the design you can't have two actor with the same name in on system. As well as using `actorSelection`, it won't throw any error if actor doesn't exists, but the message won't be processed at all, it would go into DeadLetters mailbox. In this case the most reasonable solution would be to subscribe on DeadLetters with some existing actor -

```
system.eventStream.subscribe(actorRed, classOf[DeadLetter])
```

You can intercept DeadLetter in your receive method:

```
def receive = {
  case DeadLetter(msg, from, to) =>
    // process message
}
```

With this you might use `actorSelection` and when you receive a DeadLetter create an actor, then `actorSelection` should work as expected